# Notepad++ move end text to the begining of line

Tags: notepad++

i have bunch of text in a line looks like this:

```
Arnold Sweet - A+
Ashley C. D. - B+
Steve Crook Dewl - A-
Tanya A - Absence w/e
```

and more...

How do i make all line into:

```
A+ - Arnold Sweet
B+ - Ashley C. D.
A- - Steve Crook Dewl
Absence w/e - Tanya A
```

tnx

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+?) - (.+?)$`
- Replace with: `$2 - $1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
(.+?)   : group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
 -      : literally a space, a dash, a space
(.+?)   : group 2, 1 or more any character, not greedy
$       : end of line
```

Comment: what is the `?` for?

Comment: @bolov: it is the non greedy quantifier, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: thank you. I know I could have used it a couple of times :p